# How to end line with a <a href=""> using css

Tags: css

I'm working on a psd to html and I have an  image like so:

[image]

So meaning I have a `<a href=""></a>` tag with Image. My problem now is how can I design the link in there? Do I need to have a `<br />` after the text or what?

```
   <ul id="steps-nav">
                <li>
                    <img src="img/building-details.png" alt="Building Details"/>
                    <a href="#">STEP 1: ENTER YOUR BUILDING  DETAILS</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="img/electricity-details.png" alt="Electricity Details"/>
                    <a href="#">STEP 2: ENTER YOUR
                        ELECTRICITY DETAILS</a>
                </li>
   </ul>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
  #steps-container{
            background-color:#0a0806;
            opacity: 0.7;
            margin-top: 43px;
            border-bottom: solid 10px #abd038;
        }

        #steps-container .steps{
            width:960px;
            margin:auto;
            height:50px;
        }
        #steps-container .steps ul li{
            float:left;
        }
        #steps-container .steps ul li a{
            text-decoration: none;
            color:#ffffff;
            border:solid 1px;
        }
        #steps-container .steps ul li a:after{
            content:"\A"; white-space:pre;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem 1: You want the image to be clickable with the link.

Solution: Wrap the `a` anchor around the image and the text, not just the text.

Problem 2: You want the text to be on multiple lines next to it.

Solutions:

a. You could go in the general direction you were trying, directly attaching the image and putting text next to it.

b. You could set the image as a background with padding. The image itself would not be accessible via the alt attribute, but the label does provide that extra information.

http://jsfiddle.net/D4vyM/

This will make the list items in the same line:

```
#steps-nav li {    
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Make the anchor fill up the box created by the list item and make space for the image:

```
.some-step {
    padding-left: 50px;
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

And we will add styling to the text being focused on, which is also brought to the new line:

```
.step-focus {
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `<a>` tag inside `<div>` tag. Should do the trick. `<div>` tags are acceptable inside the [li](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/li.html)

If you can't use div then use:

```
a:after { content:"\A"; white-space:pre; }
```

**EDIT**

Just use `<br />` tag.

Comment: You mean `<li> | <div> | <a>` ?

Comment: @user3093453 I mean `<li> <div> <a> </a> </div> </li>`.

Comment: Then I'ma set the width? How bout the image then

Comment: @user3093453 You can put an image inside the `div` tag too. Anyway, you can use the `CSS` rule I have posted. With that `CSS` rule there is no need for `div`

Comment: I tried it didn't get the same exact result can do a fiddle or jsbin?

Comment: @user3093453 You have to post your `CSS` then. You might have some rules that are important.

Comment: Ok, I just understood that I have mistaken your question. Just use `<br />` tag, it seems to be correct as you just want a line break.

Comment: It's not working though and also how can I set the font-size with that links

Comment: @user3093453 Then it is something with your `CSS`. See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V25V6/1/). Just post `JSFiddle` with your entire `HTML` and `CSS` for that block you are creating.

Answer (score 0):

Use the display property to specifies the type of box used for an element. A simple example of how to make a new line without using br in css.

Example :

```
a {
    display: block;
}
```